# Why does React require Babel and Webpack to work?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I was looking at the wiki page of vue.js and saw this:

> When compared to React development, Vue can be integrated to an
>   existing web application much more easily. Normally, a web application
>   can start using Vue immediately by simply including the Vue.js
>   JavaScript library. Usage with Webpack or Browserify, are not strictly
>   necessarily. This is in stark contrast to React development where
>   Usage with Webpack and Babel is unavoidable, therefore making
>   converting existing web application much more difficult.

Can someone explain why React needs webpack and babel? I thought you can just drop in the link to the CDN of React and it will work?

Comment: React uses JSX which is slightly different than vanilla JS so it needs to run through Babel.

Comment: But for non JSX development (Javascript only) just point to any React CDN

Answer (score 28):

No, Babel and Webpack is not necessary for React stack. You can still find other alternatives to build your favourite stack such as Browserify and Gulp.

However, if you want to make things easier, I do recommend you learn and use Babel and Webpack together with React because:

- You can use modules.
- You can use JSX with ES6.
- It support a lot of browsers
- You can use more advanced features (async/await) etc

With webpack

- You can use different loaders for sass, less, postcss etc
- You can use different plugins to optimise your build such as Uglify, HotModuleReplacement, Chunks etc

There are many more advantages to use webpack which you can find [here](http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/)

Comment: I think what he really mean is: "Is babel, webpack, browserify, gulp etc. necessary for React stack?". Note that the claim by `vue.js` is that it needs none of them because you can just start with `<script src="vue.js"></script>`

Answer (score 9):

> Can someone explain why React needs webpack and babel? I thought you can just drop in the link to the CDN of React and it will work?

React doesn't "need" babel or webpack but the library is built on the concept of using ES6 javascript syntax and JSX (essentially HTML in JS).

React however can be used without [ES6](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html) and [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html) which would remove the initial need for Babel but you would lose the potential benefits of ES6 and JSX.

Webpack is separate from React but commonly used in React projects for reasons `MattYao` mentioned.

In comparison to Vue, JSX to me brings the benefits of containing html, css and JS in one file/component which is what Single File Components in Vue also try to achieve. These would also require a build step using something like webpack as well.

Comment: The CSS and JS code can be included in HTML using style and script tags.

Comment: @Alex78191 - Sorry but that's not the same thing. A react component containing its own HTML and CSS within the JS files allows for the piece of the application to be abstracted and isolated from other components. Simply putting CSS and JS code into a HTML file doesn't do this as now the JS code cannot interact with code from another HTML file nor is it now in 'components'. Once complied, yes, its usually just one html, css and js file but most react/angular/vue apps wouldn't be coded like this, only compiled.

Answer (score 2):

React uses JSX syntax to make writing react more familiar to we the programmers. However, the browsers do not understand JSX. Therefore babel is required to convert your JSX into javascript which is then manipulated by ReactDom and then input into your DOM for the browsers to understand.