# How to Transfer Working HTML, CSS, Javascript Code from Codepen to Visual Studio Code and Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

My code works on codepen but not outside of there using Visual Studio Code to create my files (which are: `Quote.html`, `Quote.css`, `Quote.js` all in the same folder).

When I open my `html` file in a browser I get a green screen, so the `css` file links correctly but the `js` file does not.

According to what I have read on Stackoverflow I am putting in the `js` file in the script correctly as I understand it, but something I am doing is wrong. I

HTML file code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Quote.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
        <script src="Quote.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

//css file code:

    body {background-color: green; color: white;}
    #quote-box {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Javascript file code:

```
    const quotes = [
    {
    quote: "Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.",
    author: "Dr. Seuss"
    },
    {
    quote: "You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough.",
    author: "Mae West"
    },
    {
    quote: "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.",
    author: "Oscar Wilde"
    },
    {
    quote:
    "Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe.",
    author: "Albert Einstein"
    },
    { quote: "So many books, so little time.", author: "Frank Zappa" },
    {
    quote: "A room without books is like a body without a soul.",
    author: "Marcus Tullius Cicero"
    },
    {
    quote:
    "If you want to know what a man's like, take a good look at how he treats his inferiors, not his equals.",
    author: "J.K. Rowling"
    }
    ];
    class Presentational extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        quote: "If you want to know what a man's like, take a good look at how he treats his inferiors, not his equals.", author: "J.K. Rowling"
      }
    this.newQuote = this.newQuote.bind(this);
    this.sendTweet = this.sendTweet.bind(this);
    }
    newQuote() {
    const randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    this.setState({quote: quotes[randNumber].quote, author: quotes[randNumber].author})
    }
    sendTweet = () => {
    const url = "twitter.com";
    const text = this.state.quote.concat(" - ").concat(this.state.author); 
    window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&text='+encodeURIComponent(text), '', 'left=0,top=0,width=550,height=450,personalbar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0');
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div id="quote-box" class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="col-md-3"></h1>
          <h1 class="text-center col-md-6">Random Quotes:</h1>
          <h1 class="col-md-3"></h1>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
          <p class="col-md-3"></p>
          <blockquote class="col-md-6">
           <p id="text"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> {this.state.quote} <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i></p>
               <cite id="author">-- {this.state.author}</cite>
          </blockquote>
          <p class="col-md-3"></p>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">  
          <p class="col-md-3"></p>
          <button id="new-quote" class="btn btn-default col-md-1" onClick={this.newQuote}>New Quote</button>
          <p class="col-md-3"></p>
            <a  id="tweet-quote" onClick={this.sendTweet} class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-default col-md-2">Tweet Quote <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></button></a>
          <p class="col-md-3"></p>
        </div>  
        </div>
      );
    }
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<Presentational />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

This is the Codepen link to what should be displayed: https://codepen.io/EOJA/pen/MRNoBq

Comment: Did you set up your local environment...?

Comment: I'm learning to code, from what I read by googling "local environment" my understanding is that it is set up - meaning I have some .html, .css, and .js files in a folder on my computer.  Using examples from the internet, saved to my computer in the same way, I can open the .html file with my browser to view the website.  However, for the files in my question I am not able to view the website - it is just a green screen.

Comment: Is my understanding of local environment wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at you code, your project directory should be like this for it to work:

```
Project_Folder
| index.html
| Quote.css
| Quote.js
```

**Edit**: After looking into this matter for a while, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931538/how-to-load-es6-react-babel-code-in-html-with-cdn) to help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }
        
        #quote-box {
            margin-top: 80px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <script type='text/babel'>
       // !! IMPORTANT README:

// You may add additional external JS and CSS as needed to complete the project, however the current external resource MUST remain in place for the tests to work. BABEL must also be left in place. 
const quotes = [
  {
    quote: "Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.",
    author: "Dr. Seuss"
  },
  {
    quote: "You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough.",
    author: "Mae West"
  },
  {
    quote: "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.",
    author: "Oscar Wilde"
  },
  {
    quote:
    "Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe.",
    author: "Albert Einstein"
  },
  { quote: "So many books, so little time.", author: "Frank Zappa" },
  {
    quote: "A room without books is like a body without a soul.",
    author: "Marcus Tullius Cicero"
  },
  {
    quote:
    "If you want to know what a man's like, take a good look at how he treats his inferiors, not his equals.",
    author: "J.K. Rowling"
  }
];
class Presentational extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
  quote: "If you want to know what a man's like, take a good look at how he treats his inferiors, not his equals.", author: "J.K. Rowling"
   }
    this.newQuote = this.newQuote.bind(this);
    this.sendTweet = this.sendTweet.bind(this);
 }
  newQuote() {
    const randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    this.setState({quote: quotes[randNumber].quote, author: quotes[randNumber].author})
  }
  sendTweet = () => {
    const url = "twitter.com";
    const text = this.state.quote.concat(" - ").concat(this.state.author); 
    window.open('http://twitter.com/share?url='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&text='+encodeURIComponent(text), '', 'left=0,top=0,width=550,height=450,personalbar=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0');
  }
 render() {
   return (
  <div id="quote-box" class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h1 class="col-md-3"></h1>
          <h1 class="text-center col-md-6">Random Quotes:</h1>
          <h1 class="col-md-3"></h1>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">
          <p class="col-md-3"></p>
          <blockquote class="col-md-6">
           <p id="text"><i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i> {this.state.quote} <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i></p>
        <cite id="author">-- {this.state.author}</cite>
          </blockquote>
          <p class="col-md-3"></p>
        </div>  
        <div class="row">  
          <p class="col-md-3"></p>
          <button id="new-quote" class="btn btn-default col-md-1" onClick={this.newQuote}>New Quote</button>
          <p class="col-md-3"></p>
     <a  id="tweet-quote" href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet" onClick={this.sendTweet} class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-default col-md-2">Tweet Quote <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></button></a>
          <p class="col-md-3"></p>
        </div>  
  </div>
   );
 }
  };
ReactDOM.render(<Presentational />, document.getElementById("app"));


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I changed the name of my html file from Quote.html to index.html but I still get the same result - a green screen (background color set to green by the css file) but none of the js file rendered.

Comment: The name of html file have no effect on this issue. I just notice that in codepen you were using babel. The easiest way is just to use the View compiled JS (you can find in at js tab dropdown option). If not you really need to setup you local environment.

Comment: @eoaja please refer the updated solution if it work.

Comment: @eoaja, glad to help. Can you pick my answer as solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a React expert, but I believe you are missing Babel.

In case here, I was able to get example to work by inlining your Javascript, and including Babel as another script source.

```
<!-- Bottom of index.html -->   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
... Your JS code
<script>
```

Reference: [Why does React require Babel and Webpack to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175140/why-does-react-require-babel-and-webpack-to-work)

---

Edit:

You can avoid inlining your Javascript by referencing Quote.js as so:

`<script type='text/babel' src='Quote.js'></script>`

and then spinning up local server and calling file that way.

Reference: [How do you set up a local testing server?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server)

Comment: Yes! The problem was babel!  I had to put the compiled js in the Quote.js file for it to work without using the inline method.